# C# - Download Directory - FTP

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to download a directory, using FTP in a C# application. I basically need to take a remote dir, and move it, and its contents into a local dir.

Here is the function I'm currently using, and what the log output and errors are. The sample I'm referencing is for getting files, and possibly not directories:

```
    private void Download(string file, string destination)
    {                       
        try
        {
            string getDir = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + ftpPath + file + "/";
            string putDir = destination + "\\" + file;

            Debug.WriteLine("GET: " + getDir);
            Debug.WriteLine("PUT: " + putDir);

            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                

            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create
               (new Uri(getDir));

            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID,
                                                       ftpPassword);
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;

            reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;                
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;                                
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;                 
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(putDir, FileMode.Create);                
            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);               
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }                
            writeStream.Close();
            response.Close(); 
        }
        catch (WebException wEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
        }
    }
```

Debug:

```
GET: ftp://I.P.ADDR/SOME_DIR.com/members/forms/THE_FOLDER_TO_GET/
PUT: C:\Users\Public\Documents\iMacros\Macros\THE_FOLDER_TO_WRITE
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
```

MessageBox Output:

```
The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.
```

Comment: Does the destination directory exist on the FTP server? Does the user you are using have the right permissions?

Comment: @Oded: It does, and the user does. I previously list the directory and create a CheckedListBox of the directories as options. I can also use FileZilla to manually get the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slash on the end of the getDir indicates a directory - can you use mget and pass a path like that ends in "/*"?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by `mget`, but adding a * to the end of the request doesn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of command line FTP where mget is the command for getting multiple files.  It looks like there's no equivalent in WebRequestMethods.Ftp.  How about using the ListDirectory method to get a listing then looping though that?

Comment: I've accepted your answer, because the `mget` gave me the idea of listing the dir's contents, and looping though them one at a time getting them.

Comment: @Josh - That is really the only to do something like this.